Yolov5 Custom Model Deployment in Raspberry Pi 3
I want to deploy my pre-trained Yolov5 Custom object detection model where my datasets had used. But I did not know how to deploy this model and test it into raspberry pi 3. I did not find any tutorial based on this particular problem.
Please Help Me!
I have trained the Yolov5 model. But I don't know how to deploy it into raspberry pi.

I suggest you use Jetson, the raspberry pi 3 doesn't have the hardware performance for running yolov5 models.
Maybe yolov5s can but it depends on inference time and the frame rate.
